# Como hago para poder alinear la img "Dernocua" con la navbar, q en este caso queda debajo

Tags: html, css, web, imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero crear una navbar con el nombre del comercio. Para un proyecto de un curso.

Logre hacer funcionar el navbar, solo me falta ubicar sus elementos. Pero el nombre del comercio está escrito como en su logo, por lo que es una imagen (achicada por medio de código).

Pero no logro hacer que el texto quede alineado en el medio con la imagen. Por lo que me queda la imagen, y abajo las palabras de navegación. Tampoco puedo centrarlas en el medio del navbar.

```css
/* Controla tam img */
img {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
}

/* header (navbar) */
.Logo {
display: block;
align-items: center;
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
}

header {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 10%;
padding: 10px 30px;
background-color: #DDA15E;
transition: all .50s ease;
}

.Links a {
align-items: center;
color: #283618;
font-size: 1.5rem;
font-weight: 200;
padding: 5px 0;
margin: 0px 30px;
transition: all .50s ease;
}

.Links li {
display: inline;
padding-right: 5px;
}

.Links a:hover {
text-shadow: #283618 1px 1px;
color: #ff7b08;
}
```

```html
<header> 
    <div class="navbar"><!-- Menú de Nav --> 
        <a href="index.html" class="Logo"><img src="./Img/Solo letras.png" alt="Nombre Dernocua"></a>
        <nav> 
            <ul class="Links">
                <li><a href="./pages/Contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
                <li><a href="./pages/Nosotros.html">Nosotros</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="./pages/Productos.html">Productos</a></li>
                <li><a href="./pages/Ubicación.html">Ubicación</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Te refieres a que el logo esté en el centro del cuadro naranja?...

Comment: No, el logo está bien donde está. Quisiera poner Contacto Nosotros Inicio Productos Ubicación, alineados con el logo y esos si en el centro del cuadrado naranja. En realidad la ubicación es secundario, lo que más quisiera saber es como alinearlos

Comment: Vale, entiendo...

Comment: Si, llegas a encontrar una respuesta te lo agradeceria bastante. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A la clase `navbar`(que encierra a tu imagen) y a la etiqueta `nav` (que encierra al `ul` y los `li`), los hice flexibles para que estén uno al lado del otro y que estén alineados al centro del cuadro naranja:

```
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Luego, a la clase `Links` (que es el `ul` que encierra a los `li`), también lo convertí en flexible para poder aplicarle un espaciado llamado `space-between`, en donde esta propiedad hace que el contenido de adentro estén separados entre sí ocupando todo el contenedor de `Links`:

```
.Links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

También, otro detalle que me percaté es que tu clase `logo` (que encierra a tu imagen) y la etiqueta `header` tienen una altura fija, de la cual es incorrecto porque para las pantallas con otras resoluciones, el `header` y tu imagen se verán más pequeños y no respetarán la altura de la imagen o la imagen se saldrá fuera del `header`, así que estas clases deberían quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
.Logo {
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    /* height: 100px; */
    width: 200px;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 10%; */
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #DDA15E;
    transition: all .50s ease;
}
```

---

Código completo:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.Logo {
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  width: 70px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: #dda15e;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav {
  width: 60%;
}

.Links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.Links a {
  align-items: center;
  color: #283618;
  font-size: 1.0rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.Links li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.Links a:hover {
  text-shadow: #283618 1px 1px;
  color: #ff7b08;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="index.html" class="Logo"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" alt="Nombre Dernocua"></a>
    <nav>
      <ul class="Links">
        <li><a href="./pages/Contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
        <li><a href="./pages/Nosotros.html">Nosotros</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="./pages/Productos.html">Productos</a></li>
        <li><a href="./pages/Ubicación.html">Ubicación</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias! Y sabes si se puede hacer sin el flex?? xq primero había usado esa propiedad y me había salido y los del curso me dijeron que para la primera entrega del proyecto no puedo usar flex ._.   Para mi es complicarla mucho, ya que como vos me mostraste, es  mucho más fácil. De todas formas, gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Si, el problema es que al no usar flex, habrán problemas con el tamaño y espaciado del contenido del header en pantallas de otras resoluciones, para ello tendrías que manejar bien los media queries e indicar ciertos cambios de propiedades cuando la pantalla esté en distintas resoluciones (`px`), sin embargo, este detalle no lo habías comentado en tu pregunta... Recuerda verificar la respuesta si te sirvió marcándole al ✔️ para que tu pregunta esté como respondida, saludos.